# copy values in a dataframe according to specific filter

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

| time | open | close | giorno | ora |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 08:00:00 | 152.03 | 152.31 | 1 | 8 |
| 2021-09-01 09:00:00 | 152.21 | 152.28 | 1 | 9 |
| 2021-09-01 10:00:00 | 152.27 | 153.89 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-09-01 11:00:00 | 153.9 | 154.31 | 1 | 11 |
| 2021-09-01 12:00:00 | 154.32 | 154.28 | 1 | 12 |
| 2021-09-01 13:00:00 | 154.28 | 153.44 | 1 | 13 |
| 2021-09-02 08:00:00 | 152.98 | 153.27 | 2 | 8 |
| 2021-09-02 09:00:00 | 153.27 | 153.56 | 2 | 9 |
| 2021-09-02 10:00:00 | 153.54 | 153.94 | 2 | 10 |
| 2021-09-02 11:00:00 | 153.94 | 153.83 | 2 | 11 |
| 2021-09-02 12:00:00 | 153.84 | 153.36 | 2 | 12 |
| 2021-09-02 13:00:00 | 153.36 | 153.08 | 2 | 13 |
| 2021-09-03 08:00:00 | 153.67 | 153.96 | 3 | 8 |
| 2021-09-03 09:00:00 | 153.68 | 153.92 | 3 | 9 |
| 2021-09-03 10:00:00 | 153.96 | 154.11 | 3 | 10 |
| 2021-09-03 11:00:00 | 154.11 | 153.67 | 3 | 11 |
| 2021-09-03 12:00:00 | 153.66 | 153.76 | 3 | 12 |
| 2021-09-03 13:00:00 | 153.77 | 153.63 | 3 | 13 |
| 2021-09-07 08:00:00 | 154.07 | 154.46 | 7 | 8 |
| 2021-09-07 09:00:00 | 154.38 | 154.72 | 7 | 9 |
| 2021-09-07 10:00:00 | 154.72 | 155.49 | 7 | 10 |
| 2021-09-07 11:00:00 | 155.47 | 155.8 | 7 | 11 |
| 2021-09-07 12:00:00 | 155.79 | 155.59 | 7 | 12 |
| 2021-09-07 13:00:00 | 155.58 | 156.87 | 7 | 13 |

I want to copy the value in this way:

```
if  "ora"=10 then copy "open" cell in all the rows in the same day (column "giorno") in a new column
```

For exemple  about the time 2021-09-01 10:00:00 i want to copy the value 152.27 and past to a new column corrisponding to the rows of giorno=1

| time | open | close | giorno | ora | newColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 08:00:00 | 152.03 | 152.31 | 1 | 8 | 152.27 |
| 2021-09-01 09:00:00 | 152.21 | 152.28 | 1 | 9 | 152.27 |
| 2021-09-01 10:00:00 | 152.27 | 153.89 | 1 | 10 | 152.27 |
| 2021-09-01 11:00:00 | 153.9 | 154.31 | 1 | 11 | 152.27 |
| 2021-09-01 12:00:00 | 154.32 | 154.28 | 1 | 12 | 152.27 |
| 2021-09-01 13:00:00 | 154.28 | 153.44 | 1 | 13 | 152.27 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a lambda function to achieve this.

```py
df['newColumn'] = df.apply(lambda x: float(df['open'][(df['giorno'] == x['giorno']) & (df['ora'] == 10)]), axis=1)
```

full code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70914561/copy-values-in-a-dataframe-according-to-specific-filter')[0]
df['newColumn'] = df.apply(lambda x: float(df['open'][(df['giorno'] == x['giorno']) & (df['ora'] == 10)]), axis=1)
df[df['giorno'] == 1]
```

output:

```
    time                open    close   giorno  ora newColumn
0   2021-09-01 08:00:00 152.03  152.31  1       8   152.27
1   2021-09-01 09:00:00 152.21  152.28  1       9   152.27
2   2021-09-01 10:00:00 152.27  153.89  1       10  152.27
3   2021-09-01 11:00:00 153.90  154.31  1       11  152.27
4   2021-09-01 12:00:00 154.32  154.28  1       12  152.27
5   2021-09-01 13:00:00 154.28  153.44  1       13  152.27
```

Comment: I have the error "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>" in my df. If I  put str instead of float  the cell have a value of this: "time 2021-09-02 10:00:00 153.536718 2021-11-02 10:00:00 148.374226 2021-12-02 10:00:00 159.720000 Name: open, dtype: float64" . I used so this code "testDurataOperazione['AperturaOre10'] = testDurataOperazione.apply(lambda x: float(testDurataOperazione['open'][(testDurataOperazione['giorno'] == x['giorno']) &(testDurataOperazione['mese'] == x['mese']) &(testDurataOperazione['anno'] == x['anno']) & (testDurataOperazione['ora'] == 10)]), axis=1)"

Comment: @AlessandroG - without seeing the data is hard to tell, but I think there's a problem with the 'mese' column. Based on the filtering you get 3 results instead of one. 'mese' is the only one that doesn't match. How do you extract the month from the 'time' column?

Comment: i used df.index.month. In this example I removed some columns. In your formula I inserted also the month and year in order to compare the values. Only this. Instead I like your solution but I didn't understand how it works. In particular float